# ember.js: giving a format to urls in link_to

Tags: ember.js

I'm a newbie in ember, and i can't find anywhere where i can append a format to my links.

I have to show a pdf coming from my server, and in rails i would do it in this way:

`<%= link_to "Print", document, format: pdf %>`

asssuming that my server is actually responding at `documents/:id.pdf`, how can i build this link in ember, when i'm inside a cycle of this type?

```
{{#each document in controller}}
  ...print document link here...
{{/each}}
```

thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember's `{{linkTo}}` is for internal links.

If you want to link to an external resource, you should either user [`{{bindAttr}}` on an `<a>` tag](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_binding-element-attributes), or [write a custom Handlebars helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_writing-custom-helpers).

Comment: trying to write it in the right syntax... however... something like this?

HELPER: Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('document_pdf_url', `function(document) {
  return 'documents/' + document.id + ".pdf";
});`

TEMPLATE: `<a target="_blank" {{bindAttr href="transport_document_pdf_url(transport_document)"}}>Print</a>`

Comment: No. Handlebars feature set does not expand to function calls in helper arguments. Read through http://handlebarsjs.com/ to get a perspective about what features are supported in the templates, it's an excellent introduction/manual.

Comment: Did it in 2 ways with <a {{bindAttr}}> solution: 1) My server-side json returned the url i needed 2) My model had a computed property to calculate it . The way i would want to do it is having a controller or model computed property (as option 2) that returns me the url of the resource, concatenated with .pdf.   Is there a method "App.DocumentRoute.path or similar" that gives me the correct url?
however i understood what i can and what i can't do in a hbl, thanks